# Rails and HAML - how to reference deeply nested array items individually

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm working on someone else's site, and am trying to reference a value's ID in my HAML file, but I've tried every iteration I can think of and can't figure out how to do this. I'm trying to get the ID of a want, which belongs to a project, which belongs to a user. Here's some code from the projects model:

```
class Project
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :wants
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :wants
```

In another view, someone's written this:

```
  (id="project_#{ project.id }_wants")= render project.wants, :user => project.user
```

This returns an array of wants, which it iterates through. I was initially confused because the wants seem to have ids in some of the views, but when I tried referencing project.want[0], for example, that worked perfectly. My question is - how do I pass user(id of blah).project(id of blah).want[place blah in array] ?

Comment: What error do you get and which line is throwing that error?

Comment: Sometimes it's not an error - when I try to link to project.wants("project_#{ project.id }_wants")), :user => project.user I get the bizarre URL http://localhost:3000/users/2/lightbox?want_offered_id%5B%5D=1&want_offered_id%5B%5D=2 It's like it's loading all the wants as one "unit" and assigning them numbers on the fly. Should I iterate through them?

Comment: The trouble is, I want to filter by the want ID, even if it's assigned on the fly

Comment: Further investigation reveals the wants are definitely an array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the user ID and project ID (we'll call them user_id and project_id), you can:

```
User.find(user_id).projects.find(project_id).wants[index of the want you want]
```

or

```
User.find(user_id).projects.find(project_id).wants.find(wants_id)
```